# Reset text rotation in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, transform, rotate

I've rotated multiple texts with the transform tool in Photoshop by an arbitrary angle.
Now, I need to reset that rotation, and have the text straight. I am not able to do it by hand, its always somehow rotated and its not precise.

Is there an automatic way to do it? something like "reset transformation" or along that lines? What is the fastest way to reset those strings?

Comment: Hey @sharkyenergy, accept the answer from Chinthaka Fernando

Answer (score 5):

Photoshop doesn't remember arbitrary rotations of objects.  However, there is one rather cumbersome way you could do it.

1. Select and highlight the text with the text tool
2. Copy the text <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Select the move tool <kbd>V</kbd>
4. Select the text tool <kbd>T</kbd> again
5. Click on the image to make a new text layer
6. Paste the text <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.  Note: for Macs use <kbd>Command</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
7. Finally delete the rotated text layer

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using this technique since all text layers have also layer effects applied that i would have to copy over too.... maybe it can be done with a macro?

Comment: If you mean an Action, possibly some of it could be automated.  A script is also a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Set it to 0 again in propities pannel
[image]

Comment: Saviour of the decade! I was looking for this for ages. And it works with other elements too .